# How to create bean when class is implementing EnvironmentPostProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I want to override /actuator/health for this I have wrote a custom class (CustomHealth.java) and override `getHealth()` But I am unable to create Bean, So when I call /actuator/health, It have to call my custom implementation.

**CustomEnvironemtPostProcessor**

```
Class CustomEnvironemtPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        application.addInitializers(new CustomApplicationContextInitializer());
       .....
   
    }
}
```

**CustomApplicationContextInitializer**

```
class CustomApplicationContextInitializer implements  ApplicationContextInitializer {

@Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {       
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory
                = applicationContext.getBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.registerSingleton("customHealth", CustomHealth.class);
    }
}
```

**CustomHealth**

public class CustomHealth implements HealthIndicator {

```
public Health getHealth(boolean includeDetails) {
    return this.health();
}

@Override
public Health health() {
    double chance = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();
    Health.Builder status = Health.up();
    if (chance > 0.9) {
        status = Health.down();
    }
    return status.build();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to create such a complicated setup for Health Indicators:

Just Implement the `HealthIndicator` interface and register it as a spring bean:

```
@Component
public class RandomHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
         double chance = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();
         Health.Builder status = Health.up();
         if (chance > 0.9) {
            status = Health.down();
         }
         return status.build();
    }
}
```

Instead of `@Component` you can use the configuration approach:

```
// no @Component annotation here
public class RandomHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
...
}

@Configuration
public class MyHealthIndicatorExtensionsConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public RandomHealthIndicator randomHealthIndicator() {
      return new RandomHealthIndicator();
   }
}
```

For complete example and explanations, see [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-health-indicators).